# PHP 7.0 loaded instead of PHP 7.2 on ubuntu server after upgrade

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-16.04, php-7.2, bad-gateway

I need to install PHP 7.2 on a Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS server running PHP 7.0 with fpm.

I've installed php7.2, php7.2-fpm, enabled the module, disabled 7.0, set the alternatives

```
/etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php7.2
/etc/alternatives/php-cgi -> /usr/bin/php-cgi7.2
/etc/alternatives/php-cgi-bin -> /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.2
/etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock -> /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
```

If I stop or uninstall php7.0-fpm and use php7.2-fpm I'm getting a 502 bad gateway error
If I restart php7.0-fpm 502 bad gateway error disappear but PHP 7.0.33 is loaded

Apache version is: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Configuration

```
<IfModule !mod_php7.c>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        # Deny access to raw php sources by default
        # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
        # only in specific virtual host or directory
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
    # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Wrong version in vhosts config?

Comment: @SubCore code added to post :( all seems ok

Comment: `mod_php7` randomly on the server? then they don't load the fpm config.

Comment: No, mod_php7 works correctly

Answer (score 0):

If your php_mod works correctly, you didn't load the proxy_fcgi_module Module. You must remove the `<IfModule !mod_php7.c>` around the `<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>` like this config.

```php
<IfModule !mod_php7.c>
</IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        # Deny access to raw php sources by default
        # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
        # only in specific virtual host or directory
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
    # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: removed, with no result :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I discovered the issue.

On the server there is Cady configured and in /etc/caddy/Caddyfile php fpm was set to 7.0

I've solved symlinking php7.0 to 7.2 in /run/php to not have to mess with the Caddyfile.